# rails2 nested namespace with root path to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-2

In rails 3.1.1, I have admin_root_path set in my routes.rb as:

```
namespace :admin do
  root :to => "base#index"
  resources :users
end
```

Which routes to the index action on the admin/base_controller.
But for reasons beyond my control, I have to downgrade my rails 3 app to v2.3.14.
I've tried:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :users, :controller => "base", :action => "index"
end
```

with no luck. I know it's weird to ask a "make my new code old" question, but what the heck. I guess that's why I'm not the boss??

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You have two options as far as I can see:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.root :controller => "base"
  admin.resources :users, :controller => "users", :action => "index"
end
```

The above will give you the same `admin_root_path` as you were getting in Rails 3, but without the ability to have multiple formats.  `rake routes` shows this as:

```
admin_root   /admin   { :controller => "admin/base", :action => "index" }
```

If you wish to have multiple formats in the same way as you could in Rails 3, then I think this is your only solution:

```
map.admin_root "/admin(.:format)", :controller => "admin/base", :action => "index"

map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :users, :controller => "users", :action => "index"
end
```

The above provides this for `admin_root_path` in Rails 2.3.14 which is exactly the same as what I'm seeing in Rails 3.0.11:

```
admin_root   /admin(.:format)   { :controller => "admin/base", :action=>"index" }
```